# VBscript multiple conditions

Tags: vbscript, mailing

I'm not a programmer, just a little geek, but I'm trying to build up a vb script for a mailing software I use. It should write in the body of the email something depending on the non-numerical values present in two fields of the records of the various contacts, "company" (so, the company name) and "category".
What I exactly need is that if the company name is unknown, it just writes nothing but if it is known, then if the category is VENUE, then it writes down "at " but if it is whatever else category, it writes down "with ". Here is what I'm trying but, naturally, it's not working. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
if Contact.Field("company") = "" Then
  document.write("")
Else
if Contact.Field("category") = "VENUE" Then
document.write("at " & Contact.Field("company"))

if Contact.Field("category") = "INSTITUTION" Then
document.write("with " & Contact.Field("company"))

if Contact.Field("category") = "ASSOCIATION" Then
document.write("with " & Contact.Field("company"))

if Contact.Field("category") = "EV.ORG." Then
document.write("with " & Contact.Field("company"))

if Contact.Field("category") = "AGENCY" Then
document.write("with " & Contact.Field("company")
```

Comment: what you mean it is not working? is there any error? or wrong result?

Comment: Hi Ali, it doesn't give the desired result... no result at all. Every time I do a modification to the code, I send the email to myself to see if it is working... and it's not. It just leaves an empty space in the email body.

Comment: I'd like to know, basically, how to put there that if Contact.Field("company") is known and Contact.Field("category") = "VENUE", then document.write("at " & Contact.Field("company")), otherwise, if if Contact.Field("company") is known BUT Contact.Field("category") is not "VENUE", then it writes down "with "

Comment: `document.write("")` is a method to push a text into the user interface. If you are using these conditons to prepare an Email body, probably you need a variable to save the result and put it in the email body. Besides `end if` is missing. it may caused an error in background

Comment: Yes, I forgot the end if. I added it but it's not working anyway. I'm trying also another solution, the one below. Clearly, I don't expect that it is gonna work, I know it's bad written. I just don't know in which order to put the things and what to put in place of "KNOWN" and how to express that "is not a venue"...

Comment: [code]if Contact.Field("company") = "" Then
  document.write("")
Else
if Contact.Field("company") is KNOWN & Contact.Field("category") = "VENUE" Then
  document.write("at ")
Else
if Contact.Field("company") is KNOWN & Contact.Field("category") = NOT "VENUE"
  document.write("with " & Contact.Field("company"))
End If[/code]

Answer (score 0):

As Ali Sheikhpour stated in the comments, `document.write` is for displaying something in a web page, and I'm not sure that is what you want to do. If it is, then the code looks like it would work, but could be simplified:

```
Dim co
co = Contact.Field("company")
If co = "" Then
    document.write("")
Else
    Select Case Contact.Field("category")
        Case "VENUE"
            document.write("at " & co)
        Case "INSTITUTION", "ASSOCIATION", "EV.ORG.", "AGENCY"
            document.write("with " & co)
        Case Else    ' Any other possibilities? Otherwise, nothing will be written.
    End Select
End If
```

If this isn't working, I suspect you need to replace the `document.write` with something else, such as file system manipulation. Just where *do* you want the output to go?

Also, do you really need to write nothing, or is *doing* nothing enough? I have no vision as to what the rest of the output is or how it should look.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks very much for your help. It's still not working. I need it for a mailing software called "Sendblaster 4". This script should help me to build up a little part of the email body. Basically, I don't want to lose time doing different lists, one for venues and festivals and one for all the others because it would mean also planning two sendings.

Comment: "As Ali Sheikhpour stated in the comments, document.write is for displaying something in a web page" - There are other default (and working) scripts in this software using document.write.

Comment: I still don't understand how the generated strings are supposed to go where you want them. Are you building the email body with a string or something? Just where is `document.write` supposed to write to? The software seems to be basically a mailmerge, and I'm unfamiliar with the syntax specific to it.